# Get Spring MessageContext

Tags: spring, get, message

How to get Spring `MessageContext` from Java class?

Should I use some `@Resource` or `@Autowire` to inject `context` var to class or, for instance, to use some global context SpringContext or some other in order to get `MessageContext`.

What is approach?

Comment: Are you using SWS? If so, which version? And where do you want to access the MessageContext, client/server?

Comment: I need to get MessageContext from Java bean from method with ActioListener param,which is invoked from .xhtml(i.e. jsf page). I use Spring web-flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start by reading what the [standard method of doing this is](http://jax-ws.java.net/articles/MessageContext.html) and try that:

```
@Resource WebServiceContext wsContext;

@WebMethod public String echoHello(String msg) {
    MessageContext context = wsContext.getMessageContext();

    ...
}
```

That's how to do it on the server side. On the client side, the request and response contexts are just simple maps that you retrieve from the service stub (which will implement [`BindingProvider`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/BindingProvider.html) even if you don't explicitly ask for it); they don't need the scope management that [`MessageContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/MessageContext.html) adds.

Comment: looks like,that I need, give you feedback as soon try it out

Comment: I think @sergionni meant another [MessageContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/binding/message/MessageContext.html).

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly You're using Spring Webflow with JSF and need to access Webflow [MessageContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/api/org/springframework/webflow/execution/RequestContextHolder.html) from within a JSF [ActionListener](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/event/ActionListener.html)?

If so You can always use the [RequestContextHolder](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/webflow/execution/RequestContextHolder.html) (watch out to use the one from Webflow, as Spring MVC has it's own!), but it uses `ThreadLocal` so it's not too elegant:

```
MessageContext messageContext = 
    RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext().getMessageContext();
```

You cannot use standard DI, as the `MessageContext` is created per each request by the `FlowExecutor` on every flow start or resume, using `MessageSource`.

Comment: In newer versions RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext() is not any more available.

Answer (score 0):

in your flow.xml add a messageContext like this:

```
   <transition on="search">
     <evaluate expression="service.search(service.id, messageContext)" result="scope" />
   </transition>`
```

in your Service.java you can use the messageContext now.

```
public List search(String serviceId, MessageContext messageContext) {       
  ...       
  messageContext.addMessage(
  ...
}
```