# How to get HttpServletRequest in apache Camel based spring-ws EIP flow

Tags: apache-camel, spring-ws

I have a simple Apache Camel EIP flow where the entry point is a spring-ws web service. How do I get access to a service request's HttpServletRequest object?

```
from("spring-ws:uri:http://localhost:8080/test-ws-1.0/ws/TestService?endpointMapping=#endpointMapping")
.log("body is:\n${body}")
.process(new HttpRequestParserProcessor())
```

I would like to be able to get the request's user principal name and request's remote IP address from within HttpRequestParserProcessor. When I debug the processor, the Exchange's in object is shown as a SpringWebserviceMessage object.

Thanks in advance,
PM.

Comment: For the HTTP component this works: `HttpServletRequest request = exchange.getIn().getBody(HttpServletRequest.class);`. Perhaps you could give it a try.

Comment: Hi @Peter, in my case the body is a SpringWebserviceMessage object and if I try to make a call like you suggested, I get request as being null.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment is wrong. On debugging, exchange.getIn() is a SpringWebserviceMessage object, and exchange.getIn().getBody() is a DOMSource object.

Comment: Perhaps you try to access the `WebServiceContext` such as described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276118/get-spring-messagecontext

Comment: Hi @Peter, I've looked at the link you suggested and tried out. I get an object instance for WebServiceContext, but I get null when I try to get its MessageContext.

Comment: Perhaps this is a bug. Did you try to invoke `getUserPrincipal()` as well?

Comment: Actually, I ran the previous code in the wrong web service. I am trying out two different web services; the first is a spring-ws service and the second is an apache-cxf service. Now, running the suggested code in the apache-cxf service, I get a non-null WebServiceContext object, null when I try to get its MessageContext and a NullPointerException when I try to get its Principal. In the spring-ws service, the same code gives me null when I try to wire in the WebServiceContext itself. Sorry for the confusion there...

Comment: With CXF you could try `org.apache.cxf.message.Message cxfMessage = in.getHeader(CxfConstants.CAMEL_CXF_MESSAGE, org.apache.cxf.message.Message.class);` and `ServletRequest request = (ServletRequest)cxfMessage.get("HTTP.REQUEST");`, see https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-cxf/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/cxf/CxfConsumerTest.java

Comment: Yes, your CXF code snippet worked perfectly for the apache-cxf service, thanks for that. I don't know if I can accept that as a final solution though as my original question was for a spring-ws service specifically? We will probably be sticking to CXF for our services in future however, so your answer is definitely useful for us! Thanks again.

Comment: Which Camel version do you use?

Comment: I added an answer to your question including a Spring Webservice solution I found.

Comment: Using Camel version 2.12.2 and your solutions below work perfectly for both, the spring-ws service and the apache-cxf service. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/common.html:

```
TransportContext context = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
HttpServletConnection connection = (HttpServletConnection )context.getConnection();
HttpServletRequest request = connection.getHttpServletRequest();
String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
```

Or use CXF instead of Spring-WS. CXF is from the same kitchen as Camel and therefore may be better integrated. With CXF you have access to the `ServletRequest` as follows (see [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-cxf/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/cxf/CxfConsumerTest.java)):

```
org.apache.cxf.message.Message cxfMessage = in.getHeader(CxfConstants.CAMEL_CXF_MESSAGE, org.apache.cxf.message.Message.class);
ServletRequest request = (ServletRequest)cxfMessage.get("HTTP.REQUEST");
```

Comment: Constant is declared in this class: `org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination`:  `public static final String HTTP_REQUEST = "HTTP.REQUEST";`